# How do I write an @if in Laravel that uses data from my database?

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and am using Laravel 6. One of my views is going to contain the values in a row of my MySQL table. The table column is a boolean so it contains either 0 or 1. Rather than displaying 0 or 1 in the view, I want to display YES or NO. An `@if` seems the logical way to do this but I can't get my `@if` to work.

```
@if ({{ $sleepDiaryEntry->outdoorLight }} == 1 )
    <p>Two hours of outdoor light? YES</p>
@else
   <p>Two hours of outdoor light? NO</p>
@endif
```

I've tried several variations of the `@if` but every variation gives me a syntax error on the first line of the `@if`.

Unfortunately, the Laravel manual is very skimpy on details of exactly what arguments can and cannot appear in an `@if`. They tend to give an example or two and think they've anticipated every possible situation and question.

How I can accomplish what I want to do, either with or without `@if`?

Comment: will better if put your error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `{{}}` in `@if`, like followings

```
@if ($sleepDiaryEntry->outdoorLight == 1 )
    <p>Two hours of outdoor light? YES</p>
@else
   <p>Two hours of outdoor light? NO</p>
@endif
```

because `{{}}` for show the variable

Comment: Thank you! Since you answered first, you get the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about what you want but by using `{{}}` you are trying to print data.

Try :

```php
@if ($sleepDiaryEntry->outdoorLight == 1 )
    <p>Two hours of outdoor light? YES</p>
@else
   <p>Two hours of outdoor light? NO</p>
@endif
```

If it doesn't work:

- Are you giving `$sleepDiaryEntry` to the view in your controller method ?
- Try to `{{ dd($sleepDiaryEntry) }}` see what you have in your view.

Comment: Simply removing the curly braces resolved the problem completely. Thank you! I misunderstood the purpose of the braces.

Answer (score 1):

`@if ({{ $sleepDiaryEntry->outdoorLight }} == 1 )` just gets rendered down to:

```
<?php if ({{ $sleepDiaryEntry->outdoorLight }} == 1 ) { ?>
```

in the final Blade template, which will cause a syntax error. You don't need the `{{ }}` tags in the conditional (not just "don't need": they won't be parsed at all here); it takes plain old PHP code in the `()`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this further. I was complicating this unnecessarily.